# how to get selected image name value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a memory game and i have some code that works if i click the image it shows the name of the image in the console.

I tried to research it but can't find any answer.
How do i select image name value for my ImageURL variable?

This is what i have now in my code:

```js
const myCardSet = ["duck", "kitten", "piglet", "puppy", "calf", "veal", "lamb", "rooster", "horse", "mouse", "dog", "cat", "goose", "goat", "sheep", "pig", "cow", "chick", "hen"];

document.addEventListener('onload', function () {
    populatieField()
})

class card {
    constructor(card1) {
        this.card1 = myCardSet[0]
    }
}

function populateField() {
    for (let i = 0; i < myCardSet.length; i++) {
        let newTile = document.createElement('div');
        let newCard = document.createElement('img');
        let imageURL = document.getElementById('field').getElementsByTagName('img')
        for (let i of imageURL) {
            let ImageSrc = i.getAttribute('name')
            console.log(ImageSrc.substring(ImageSrc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1))
        }
        newCard.setAttribute('src', imageURL)
        newCard.setAttribute('name', imageURL)
        newTile.appendChild(newCard)
        myField.appendChild(newTile)
        let img = {
            src: 'cover.png',
            class: '.covered'
        }
    }
}

const myField = document.getElementById('field')
myField.addEventListener('click', function onClickCard(e) {
    this.getAttribute(e.target.name)
    console.log(e.target.name)
}
)

function shuffle(arr) {
    var i = arr.length, j, temp;
    while (--i > 0) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
        temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[i]
        arr[i] = temp
    }
}

shuffle(myCardSet)
populateField()
```

```html
<body>

    <div id="field"><img src="../begin/img/calf.jpg" alt="" name="calf">
        <img src="../begin/img/cat.jpg" alt="" name="cat">
        <img src="../begin/img/chick.jpg" alt="" name="chick">
        <img src="../begin/img/cow.jpg" alt="" name="cow">
        <img src="../begin/img/dog.jpg" alt="" name="dog">
        <img src="../begin/img/duck.jpg" alt="" name="duck">
        <img src="../begin/img/goat.jpg" alt="" name="goat">
        <img src="../begin/img/goose.jpg" alt="" name="goose">
        <img src="../begin/img/hen.jpg" alt="" name="hen">
        <img src="../begin/img/horse.jpg" alt="" name="horse">
        <img src="../begin/img/kitten.jpg" alt="" name="kitten">
        <img src="../begin/img/lamb.jpg" alt="" name="lamb">
        <img src="../begin/img/pig.jpg" alt="" name="pig">
        <img src="../begin/img/piglet.jpg" alt="" name="piglet">
        <img src="../begin/img/puppy.jpg" alt="" name="puppy">
        <img src="../begin/img/rooster.jpg" alt="" name="rooster">
        <img src="../begin/img/sheep.jpg" alt="" name="sheep">
        <img src="../begin/img/veal.jpg" alt="" name="veal">
        <img src="../begin/img/cat.jpg" alt="" name="cat">
        <img src="../begin/img/chick.jpg" alt="" name="chick">
        <img src="../begin/img/cow.jpg" alt="" name="cow">
        <img src="../begin/img/dog.jpg" alt="" name="dog">
        <img src="../begin/img/duck.jpg" alt="" name="duck">
        <img src="../begin/img/goat.jpg" alt="" name="goat">
        <img src="../begin/img/goose.jpg" alt="" name="goose">
        <img src="../begin/img/hen.jpg" alt="" name="hen">
        <img src="../begin/img/horse.jpg" alt="" name="horse">
        <img src="../begin/img/kitten.jpg" alt="" name="kitten">
        <img src="../begin/img/lamb.jpg" alt="" name="lamb">
        <img src="../begin/img/pig.jpg" alt="" name="pig">
        <img src="../begin/img/piglet.jpg" alt="" name="piglet">
        <img src="../begin/img/puppy.jpg" alt="" name="puppy">
        <img src="../begin/img/rooster.jpg" alt="" name="rooster">
        <img src="../begin/img/sheep.jpg" alt="" name="sheep">
        <img src="../begin/img/veal.jpg" alt="" name="veal">
    </div>

    <script src="js/memory.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

I get the error 404 not found.

Please help!
thanks already!

[image: still getting error 404 and not showing images]

Comment: Use URL to image, not path of file system, as it will not work in some cases. Browser loads via URL and not via file system `src` value

Comment: `<img src="https://example.com/url/to/begin/img/piglet.jpg" alt="" name="piglet">`

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i want all images selected one by one in javascript and loop over them, how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the `img` elements that are children of the container with `id="field"`. The filename of an image can be found by using the `subString()` method and using the position of the last backslash character in the string.

```js
const imageElements = document.getElementById("field").getElementsByTagName("img");

for (let image of imageElements) {
  let imageSrc = image.getAttribute("src");
  console.log(imageSrc.substring(imageSrc.lastIndexOf("/")+1));
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div id="field"><img src="../begin/img/calf.jpg" alt="" name="calf">
        <img src="../begin/img/cat.jpg" alt="" name="cat">
        <img src="../begin/img/chick.jpg" alt="" name="chick">
        <img src="../begin/img/cow.jpg" alt="" name="cow">
        <img src="../begin/img/dog.jpg" alt="" name="dog">
        <img src="../begin/img/duck.jpg" alt="" name="duck">
        <img src="../begin/img/goat.jpg" alt="" name="goat">
        <img src="../begin/img/goose.jpg" alt="" name="goose">
        <img src="../begin/img/hen.jpg" alt="" name="hen">
        <img src="../begin/img/horse.jpg" alt="" name="horse">
        <img src="../begin/img/kitten.jpg" alt="" name="kitten">
        <img src="../begin/img/lamb.jpg" alt="" name="lamb">
        <img src="../begin/img/pig.jpg" alt="" name="pig">
        <img src="../begin/img/piglet.jpg" alt="" name="piglet">
        <img src="../begin/img/puppy.jpg" alt="" name="puppy">
        <img src="../begin/img/rooster.jpg" alt="" name="rooster">
        <img src="../begin/img/sheep.jpg" alt="" name="sheep">
        <img src="../begin/img/veal.jpg" alt="" name="veal">
        <img src="../begin/img/cat.jpg" alt="" name="cat">
        <img src="../begin/img/chick.jpg" alt="" name="chick">
        <img src="../begin/img/cow.jpg" alt="" name="cow">
        <img src="../begin/img/dog.jpg" alt="" name="dog">
        <img src="../begin/img/duck.jpg" alt="" name="duck">
        <img src="../begin/img/goat.jpg" alt="" name="goat">
        <img src="../begin/img/goose.jpg" alt="" name="goose">
        <img src="../begin/img/hen.jpg" alt="" name="hen">
        <img src="../begin/img/horse.jpg" alt="" name="horse">
        <img src="../begin/img/kitten.jpg" alt="" name="kitten">
        <img src="../begin/img/lamb.jpg" alt="" name="lamb">
        <img src="../begin/img/pig.jpg" alt="" name="pig">
        <img src="../begin/img/piglet.jpg" alt="" name="piglet">
        <img src="../begin/img/puppy.jpg" alt="" name="puppy">
        <img src="../begin/img/rooster.jpg" alt="" name="rooster">
        <img src="../begin/img/sheep.jpg" alt="" name="sheep">
        <img src="../begin/img/veal.jpg" alt="" name="veal">
    </div>

    <script src="js/memory.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works! but how do i loop over them one by one if i click on the right image? also the last images show an icon of a file, not the image itself.

Comment: Please add the JavaScript code that you are executing for the click event.

Comment: Also i still get the error 404 not found.

Comment: Looking at the error message in the image, you are attempting to load to load a HTML Collection object instead of an image. Without seeing your code it's not possible to properly determine the cause of the issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have added the rest of the code.

Comment: There are a few obvious errors in your code. `populatieField()` is called in line 3, but the function name defined is `populateField`. In the function the outer `for` loop uses the variable `i` in the condition, `let i = 0; i < myCardSet.length; i++`. The inner loop overwrites the value, `let i of imageURL`. The line `newCard.setAttribute('src', imageURL)` is where you are generating the 404 errors, the variable `imageURL` is assigned to a HTMLCollection on the DOM in a previous line, `let imageURL = document.getElementById('field').getElementsByTagName('img')`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, how do i fix the code? can you show me an example of code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257297/discussion-between-user22934804-and-dan-nagle).

Answer (score 1):

This code will iterate the collection of images you have in your html and return the src of each. You can start from here to build the logic you want (unclear from the question)

```js
/*function populateField() {
    for (let i = 0; i < myCardSet.length; i++) {
        let newTile = document.createElement('div');
        let newCard = document.createElement('img');
        let imageURL = newCard.getAttribute('name')
        newCard.setAttribute('src', imageURL)
        newCard.setAttribute('name', imageURL)
        newTile.appendChild(newCard)
        myField.appendChild(newTile)
        let img = {
            src: 'cover.png',
            class: '.covered'
        }
    }
}*/

const imageCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (let i = 0; i < imageCollection.length; i++) {
  console.log(imageCollection[i].getAttribute("name"));
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div id="field"><img src="../begin/img/calf.jpg" alt="" name="calf">
        <img src="../begin/img/cat.jpg" alt="" name="cat">
        <img src="../begin/img/chick.jpg" alt="" name="chick">
        <img src="../begin/img/cow.jpg" alt="" name="cow">
        <img src="../begin/img/dog.jpg" alt="" name="dog">
        <img src="../begin/img/duck.jpg" alt="" name="duck">
        <img src="../begin/img/goat.jpg" alt="" name="goat">
        <img src="../begin/img/goose.jpg" alt="" name="goose">
        <img src="../begin/img/hen.jpg" alt="" name="hen">
        <img src="../begin/img/horse.jpg" alt="" name="horse">
        <img src="../begin/img/kitten.jpg" alt="" name="kitten">
        <img src="../begin/img/lamb.jpg" alt="" name="lamb">
        <img src="../begin/img/pig.jpg" alt="" name="pig">
        <img src="../begin/img/piglet.jpg" alt="" name="piglet">
        <img src="../begin/img/puppy.jpg" alt="" name="puppy">
        <img src="../begin/img/rooster.jpg" alt="" name="rooster">
        <img src="../begin/img/sheep.jpg" alt="" name="sheep">
        <img src="../begin/img/veal.jpg" alt="" name="veal">
        <img src="../begin/img/cat.jpg" alt="" name="cat">
        <img src="../begin/img/chick.jpg" alt="" name="chick">
        <img src="../begin/img/cow.jpg" alt="" name="cow">
        <img src="../begin/img/dog.jpg" alt="" name="dog">
        <img src="../begin/img/duck.jpg" alt="" name="duck">
        <img src="../begin/img/goat.jpg" alt="" name="goat">
        <img src="../begin/img/goose.jpg" alt="" name="goose">
        <img src="../begin/img/hen.jpg" alt="" name="hen">
        <img src="../begin/img/horse.jpg" alt="" name="horse">
        <img src="../begin/img/kitten.jpg" alt="" name="kitten">
        <img src="../begin/img/lamb.jpg" alt="" name="lamb">
        <img src="../begin/img/pig.jpg" alt="" name="pig">
        <img src="../begin/img/piglet.jpg" alt="" name="piglet">
        <img src="../begin/img/puppy.jpg" alt="" name="puppy">
        <img src="../begin/img/rooster.jpg" alt="" name="rooster">
        <img src="../begin/img/sheep.jpg" alt="" name="sheep">
        <img src="../begin/img/veal.jpg" alt="" name="veal">
    </div>

    <script src="js/memory.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it only selects the first image from my html not the other ones. How do i select them all one by one?

Comment: no, it iterates on all and each image as you can see if you run the snippet. `for (let i = 0; i < imageCollection.length; i++) {` is the loop that goes through each one by one

Comment: that's a completely different question.